# angular-ui-bootstrap collapse by target

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

Utilizing angular-UI-Bootstrap 0.9.0, which has full bootstrap 3.0 support now. Awesome...with bootstrap 3.0, I could do the collapse by pointing to an ID target, but I can't figure out how to do that using the angular-UI code instead. It seems to just say, "find all isCollapsed and dump it no matter what" so now all collapsible/expandable containers operate at the same time not matter which collapse link you use. My code is identical to http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/collapse, but with multiple collapse objects and links within the same controller. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Shortly after posting this, I found that if you wrap each instance in the controller, each link becomes isolated. Works perfectly.

Edit: Nested controllers however do not seem to operate in the 'Collapse All/Expand All' way that I would like...Still testing.